Initializing a boolean formcontrol as null with formbuilder
I'm trying to use a radio button to get a boolean value from a user. The value should default to null, as the user hasn't answered anything yet. Here is the current implementation that works, but is ugly.
Here is my current implementation:
export class SomeComponent {
  form = this.fb.group({
    booleanInput: [null as unknown as boolean, [Validators.required]],
  });

  constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) {};

  getBoolValue() {
    return this.form.control.booleanInput.value; // return type boolean | null
  }
}

Previously I tried without the as unknown as boolean, but when the attempting to set the value (particularly in the case of unit tests) or get the value, the implied type is null, which is not what we want.
additionally, I tried with the FormControl constructor, but that has a return type of boolean | null when getting the value. example:
export class SomeComponent {
  form = this.fb.group({
    booleanInput: new FormControl<boolean | null>(null, [Validators.required]),
  });

  constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) {};

  getBoolValue() {
    return this.form.control.booleanInput.value; // return type boolean | null
  }
}

Any insight or best practice suggestions would be appreciated!

Upon further review, it turns out that ImpliedType | null is the standard return value for a strongly typed FormControl. Either option seems fine, but null as unknown as boolean seems... dirty and using the FormControl constructor breaks the standard formbuilder pattern.
